# customize or extend sharepoint gantt chart to dipslay data from multiple lists

Tags: gantt-view

I would like to display data from different lists in a gantt chart view. 
I have different lists like: Stages, categories, parts.

So data from stages List (stage1, stage2, stage3,...) will be displayed first like the image shows it below, one after the other. Not like the usual gantt chart that shows the bar in the second row.

To make the things simple I would like to start first displaying the stages list, but I don't know how to display them like the one in the image. Can anyone suggest as how can I extend or customize the default gantt chart? which classes do I have to use? Any code, links or ideas will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom gantt charts from several SharePoint vendors, like Pentalogic, VirtoSoftware or Team Direction.
They offer functionality you are looking for.